# How to insert brackets only around an operand and the following factorial (!) operator in a mathematical expression?

Tags: android, expression, factorial, insertion

User-entered expression: 2+3!-4

What I want to achieve: 2+(3!)-4

For this I understand that I can use 'replaceAll()' and replace all "!" with "!)". This solves the closing bracket insertion problem but I want to know how can I get "(" before the operand (in this case, 3) as it can be any number.

Thanks :)

Comment: You should take a look at regular expressions.

Comment: Oh! Regular expressions can help here? I will have a look. Thank you. I am already using MXParser library for calculating the expression so thought don't need Regex right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression `/(\d+\!)/g` to find the parts using a factorial. The implementation depends on what language you use.

In Java it should be something like `myString.replaceAll("(\d+\!)", "($1)");`
The $1 is a backreference to the orignial pattern.

Comment: I am using android studio for this. So its java.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate what you mean by "$1 is a backreference to the original pattern"? I am not well-versed with this vocabulary yet :)

Comment: $1 is the value/pattern that it finds. In the case of `2+3!-4` that would be `3!` so it will replace the found pattern `3!` with `(3!)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very good solution. I don't even need to replace the "!" separately as it does it all in one line. Quick and easy :)

Comment: if I want to do (!3), how can I do this. This is just to expand my understanding of regex. Will using "(\!+\d)" do it?